# Filtering pandas data frame with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I got two dataframes.first one is something like this

```
section,position
1,13
1,17
1,25
2,10
2,15
3,6
3,12
3,19
```

and second one is

```
section,position_start,position_end
1,10,14
2,2,9
2,15,16
3,18,50
```

My aim is filtering the first dataframe using the second one. I am trying to get positions that are in between position_start and position_end while also considering the sections.

Thanks

Here is the expected output considering section:

```
section,position
1,13
2,15
3,19
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['position_start'], df2['position_end'], closed='both')
df2=df2.set_index(idx)
```

---

solution

```
Mask=df1.apply(lambda x :[x['position'] in y for y in df2.loc[df2.section==x.section,].index],axis=1)
Mask=Mask.apply(lambda x :sum(x))>0
df1[Mask]

Out[121]: 
   section  position
0        1        13
4        2        15
7        3        19
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.IntervalIndex` + `get_indexer_non_unique`:

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.position_start, \
                                  df2.position_end, closed='left')    
print(idx)
IntervalIndex([[10, 14), [2, 9), [15, 16), [18, 50)]
              closed='left',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

mask = idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df.position)[0] >= 0
print(mask)
array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

---

```
print(df[mask])
   section  position
0        1        13
2        1        25
3        2        10
4        2        15
5        3         6
6        3        12
7        3        19
```

Comment: @Wen Cheers :-)

Comment: I just notice , he also need consider the section .

Comment: @Wen Since OP did not provide an expected output, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Wen Sure, I feel a bit lazy now.

Comment: Me too... cause the weather turn cold , let us blame the weather :) haha